# PHP mcrypt_encrypt/mcrypt_decrypt issue, returns a different value

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I was looking for an answer but could not find it here. Please excuse me if this question was already asked.

I have a simple code encrypting and decrypting a string, strings look the same, but when comparing them using == they do not appear to be the same, so hashes are different as well..

Here is my code:

```
$oppa = "rompish";
$opp_enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "key", $oppa, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$opp_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "key", $opp_enc, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

echo $oppa."<br />".$opp_dec."<br />";

if ($oppa == $opp_dec) echo "YAY"; else echo "NOPE";
```

On the page:

rompish
rompish
NOPE

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: AES always encrypts things in blocks of 16 bytes. Apparently `mcrypt_encrypt` pads the string out with zero bytes until it is a multiple of 16. `mcrypt_decrypt` dutifully decrypts this but lacks the information to remove the padding. And you are fooling yourself because the displayed values look the same even though `oppa_dec` actually ends with 9 zero bytes. Use a sensible padding scheme instead.

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment, GregS (make it so or I'll post it including your name at the end :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AES always encrypts things in blocks of 16 bytes. Apparently
>   `mcrypt_encrypt` pads the string out with zero bytes until it is a
>   multiple of 16. `mcrypt_decrypt` dutifully decrypts this but lacks the
>   information to remove the padding. And you are fooling yourself
>   because the displayed values look the same even though `oppa_dec`
>   actually ends with 9 zero bytes. Use a sensible padding scheme
>   instead. – [GregS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/gregs)

To remove these null characters, you can use the [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function. After running the decrypted output through that it should be equal.