# mcrypt_encrypt different result in php and ios

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, mcrypt, blowfish

I've been trying to encrypt something in PHP 5.2 like so:

```
$key = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456";//56 chars
$iv = "12345678";//8 chars
$text = "Nick is pooping.";//16 chars

$enc = mcrypt_encrypt("blowfish", $key, $text, "cbc", $iv);

var_dump($enc); echo "<br>";
var_dump(base64_encode($enc)); echo "<br>";
```

This is the output:

```
string(16) "–±–%ê„zÆtÈ¾ R" 
string(24) "lrGWJeofhHrGdMi+BiBSHQ=="
```

I'm using [this](http://codeding.com/articles/blowfish-encryption-algorithm-for-iphone) on my iOS side, with this code:

```
Blowfish* _blowfish = [BlowfishAlgorithm new];
[_blowfish setMode:[BlowfishAlorithm buildModeEnum:@"CBC"]];
[_blowfish setKey:@"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456"];
[_blowfish setInitVector:@"12345678"];
[_blowfish setupKey];
NSLog(@"%@",[_blowfish encrypt:@"Nick is pooping."]);
```

This outputs:

```
3132333435363738f61e0c4683e55fe061f1951e7a8182be
```

base64_encode doesn't do the trick in php, and I can't figure out how to match them so that they output the same. :(

Comment: I cannot see that you set the same key and initialization vector in the Objective-C code.

Comment: Whoops! My bad -- I was copying the code from VirtualBox by hand, so I messed up -- its there now.

Comment: Strange thing: if you interpret your output as hexadecimal bytes, you get the following: http://cl.ly/image/2O1Z0H3C0w3L . The first 8 chars are the IV… the rest I don’t know. I cannot download the code you link to (it ask me to register), I recommend you to look for an alternative implementation, to check if that implementation is wrongly implemented.

Comment: Check your character encodings.  I'd bet on of 'em is not like the other.

Comment: What exactly does PHP output -- what encoding is it? It looks like a bunch of gibberish and foreign language characters. How should I convert it to plain text? Should I base64 encode it or use bin2hex or pack? What's the most standard way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove these null characters, you can use the rtrim function. After running the decrypted output through that it should be equal.

Please refer to this link for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15352155/516512